# XPages: ODA-SEVERE errors when using the OpenNTF API

Tags: java, xpages

Scenario:

- open document with rich text field in a browser
- click Insert Image
- select an image and add it
- save the document

Best case, the image is stored in the document. but cannot be seen when the document is reopened. Worst case, we get a load of messages, here's an excerpt:

```
2015-06-11T10:55:51 [SEVERE]: org.openntf.domino.impl.Document.closeMIMEEntities - closeMIMEEntities returned false for item Body on doc 12562 in db CN=titan/O=SEFIP!!aalto803.nsf
java.lang.Throwable
    at org.openntf.domino.impl.Document.closeMIMEEntities(Document.java:632)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoRichTextItem.closeMIMEEntities(DominoRichTextItem.java:2722)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoRichTextItem.updateRichTextItem(DominoRichTextItem.java:1565)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.applyChangesToDoc(DominoDocument.java:1812)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.applyChanges(DominoDocument.java:1764)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument._getDocument(DominoDocument.java:649)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.getDocument(DominoDocument.java:643)
    at com.sefip.FieldData.evaluate(FieldData.java:334)
    at com.sefip.FieldData.computeHide(FieldData.java:105)
    at com.sefip.FormData.refresh(FormData.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1863.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
...
```

The com.sefip code is mine. I need an updated document, in order to do some session.evaluate calls, so I have this:

```
Document doc = (Document)xspDoc.getDocument(true);
```

Bug? In the API?

**More info:**

This is what happens when I update a document and add some rich text content, in this case with an image:

```
2015-06-12T17:30:20 [WARNING]: lotus.domino.local.NotesBase.CheckObject - null
NotesException: Object has been removed or recycled
    at lotus.domino.local.NotesBase.CheckObject(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.local.MIMEEntity.getNthHeader(Unknown Source)
    at org.openntf.domino.impl.MIMEEntity.getNthHeader(MIMEEntity.java:534)
    at org.openntf.domino.impl.MIMEEntity.getNthHeader(MIMEEntity.java:1)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoRichTextItem.getMimePartByDisposition(DominoRichTextItem.java:2535)
```

Comment: Is this in a repeat control during a partial refresh? If you're using the RichTextItem in there, it be throwing the error in Apply Request Values (I think that's the phase it hits). If you've got code that using it and calculating in a partial refresh based on it to display something, try wrapping the code in  if (view.isRenderingPhase())..., so it only runs in Render Response.

Comment: As far as I can see, there are no repeats surrounding it and a full update is executed.

Answer (score 2):

When manipulating MIME items there are some gotchas in the core Domino code. If you check the help document "Working with a MIME entity in Java classes", it talks about calling `Session.setConvertMIME(false)` before accessing the MIME items, then `Session.setConvertMIME(true)` at the end of the code.

The good news is we can do all that for you. If you use `org.openntf.domino.xsp=marcel` (as in Marcel Marceau!), it will automatically set and unset the options for converting MIME.

If you already have other switches set, they can just be comma-delimited, e.g. `org.openntf.domino.xsp=godmode,marcel,khan`.

This presentation on slideshare gives an introduction of all the switches and a summary of the code structure http://www.slideshare.net/paulswithers1/openntf-domino-api

Comment: But I wasn't even handling MIME entities on purpose... :-O

Comment: I'll add the marcel option and report back.

Comment: Therein lies the gotcha - that you can be handling MIME entities without thinking you are ;-)

Comment: Thanks, and gotcha... :-$  Anyway, it seems to have done the trick, so I moved up to the next bug (no permission to remove a document, yet I'm a manager). How is any normal human being to know that there are many interesting switches to fiddle with? Development by blundering around? ;-)

Comment: The presentation covers some, but this question and a couple of other developers starting to use ODA this week have prompted me to do some blog posts covering introductions and next steps, possibly on OpenNTF site. Ideally I'd like to do a whole site, similar to what is available for Dojo Toolkit, covering basics and code snippets. But Dojo has many more developers involved! There is also a Skype chat, contact me on Twitter (paulswithers) if you want me to add you in.

Comment: Sorry, still have exactly the same error. Very strange because yesterday I managed to save the document correctly. Marcel (Proust) is there, so is Godmode. We also found out that it's the whole rich-text field that doesn't work, not only the image. I'll add some of the log to the question text above.

Comment: I'm seeing ODA warnings in my server log as well: 

[ODA::WARNING] null
[ODA::WARNING]    (source:org.openntf.domino.utils.DominoUtils$4.run - See IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT\org.openntf.log.X.Y.txt for full stack trace.)

Comment: This seems a different error. I've not come across that. Can you paste the full stack trace from org.openntf.log.X.Y.txt (X and Y are numbers that start at 0 - so 0.0.txt for current log, 0.1 for the previous etc). The Log Reader application from OpenNTF has a tab to see these log files.